# How can I express my for loop with a foreach loop on my 2D array?

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, foreach

```
public static boolean doit(int[][] a, int b){
    for(int i=0; i<a.length; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < a[i].length; j++)
        {
            if(a[i][j] ==b) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

So basically I want to use the `ForEach` loop, for checking if the array contains the `int b`, but I'm not sure how to use it.

```
public static boolean doitTwo(int[][] a, int b){
    for(c :a){
        for ( d:a){
              if(a[c][d] ==b) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nearly there, but you're iterating over `a` in both loops when the inner loops should be using `c`. Also, when you are iterating over the values instead of the indexes like this, you don't need to index into the arrays (like you were doing with `a[c][d]`), as you already have the values in hand.

```
public static boolean doitTwo(int[][] a, int b){
    for(int[] c : a){
        for (int d : c){
              if(d ==b) {
                return true;
            }

    }

}
```

I also added types to your for loops, not strictly necessary as they can be inferred, but I prefer being explicit in Java.

The first for loop `c : a` takes a and iterates over its values. As it's a 2D array, each of it's elements are a 1D array! You then iterate over that 1D array and each values of the 1D array is int.

Example pseudocode:

```
# Original 2D array which is an array, containing arrays of ints. i.e. int[][]
x = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6];

for (a : x) {
  # at this point on the first iteration, a = [1,2,3]. i.e. int[]
  for (b : a) {
    # at this point on the first iteration, b = 1. i.e. int
  }
}
```

Comment: It works thank you, but can you explain why i have to use the first loop with an array and the second without?

Comment: @R.You The 2D array is basically an array of arrays, so when iterating through a 2D array, its elements are 1D arrays. Once you get to the second loop, you're iterating through a 1D array, so you're simply left with `int` values as elements.

Comment: I updated the answer with a more thorough explanation.

Comment: Thanks a lot, got it now.